# Enrolling in iOS Enterprise Program without the DUNS

Tags: ios

I've been searching for answer on how to deploy iOS apps without going through App Store and the only answer is through the Enterprise Program, however, we need to have the DUNS number to be enrolled in the program. We are looking on the TestFlight but it only deploys beta apps.

Is there a way we can deploy iOS apps the Enterprise way even if we are not enrolled in Enterprise? BTW, we are enrolled in iOS Developer Program.

Comment: No, you can distribute your iOS applications in 4 ways: 1) to the app store; 2) to one of your 100 provisioned devices using a profile that expires in 90 days; 3) to a licensed enterprise customer (who has a registered and valid program); or 4) from any server as long as your users are only jailbroken phones.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is, you CAN'T. DUNS number is a compulsory requirement for iOS Enterprise Program, as the number ensures you are really representing an "Enterprise".

Comment: The enterprise program is apparently open to firms smaller than 500 now as well, so I've edited your answer. You do still need a DUNS number, though.

Comment: Thanks! however our company is located outside US, can we still get DUNS number?

Comment: you can still apply for it. Some companies outside US already have their DUNS number.

Comment: What about deploying it to 3rd party (contracted) company devices?

Comment: You can use provision method provided by Apple Provisioning Portal. Requires the devices' UDID.

Answer (score 1):

The enterprise program is intended for deploying apps *within your organization*. It does allow you to deploy without going through the app store approval process, but it does not allow you to deploy to just anyone.

There's no way to deploy "the enterprise way" without being in the enterprise developer program, and you'll need a DUNS number to get into that program.

You can deploy to a small number (i.e. < 100) of devices using ad hoc deployment, but that's really intended more for testing than actual distribution. You'll need the UDID of each and every device on which you want to install the app.